# Footer always at bottom but without fixed height

Tags: html, height, footer, liquid

Can anyone help me to make an HTML code based on DIV's which has a simular result as this TABLE based code:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

<STYLE>
html,body {height:100%;}
</STYLE>

<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 height=100% width=100%>
<TR>
  <TD bgcolor=pink>
    Page content...<BR>111<BR>222<BR>333
  </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD bgcolor=yellow id=footer style="height:1%">
    Footer...<BR>111<BR>222<BR>333<BR>
    <BUTTON onclick="document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML+='<BR>more footer...';">Increase footer</BUTTON>
  </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: can you vote-up or accept the answer if it helped you !

Answer (score 0):

add this as CSS to your footer..

```
#footer{
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background-color : //whichever color you want
}
```

Comment: Tarun, I've tested your code but it doesn't work as I expected. I want the footer to be always at bottom but in your case it isn't at bottom when the content div has small height.

Comment: I misread your question then, my apologies, I'll get back as soon as possible !

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify minimum height of the center div/element.

For example following HTML snippet would ensure that footer is always at least 600px from the top of the browser

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div style="min-height: 600px;" id="center-content">

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```